# Using Windows version of Sed can I change a text file with timecode to a format for a video editing software. Also delete the first line

Tags: sed

Is it possible to use Windows version Sed to change a text file with timecode to a format for the video editing software Edius?

> %Frame Rate    3,0
>      00:00:00:00
>      00:00:00:00
>      00:01:06:15
>      00:07:19:12
>      00:09:52:03

I need to add a comma `,` then the timecode in quotation marks `"00:00:00:00"` then another comma and two quotation marks `,""`

```
,"00:00:00:00",""
,"00:01:06:15",""
,"00:07:19:12",""
,"00:09:52:03",""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed 's/^/,"/;s/$/",""/' file > file.out && mv file.out file
```

If you're using Linux it can be simplified to

```
 sed -i 's/^/,"/;s/$/",""/' file
```

Or if on MAC OS-X, then you'll need

```
 sed -i"" 's/^/,"/;s/$/",""/' file
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/.*/,"&",""/' file
,"00:00:00:00",""
,"00:01:06:15",""
,"00:07:19:12",""
,"00:09:52:03",""
```

Comment: Dear drive-by downvoter - care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I using Sed for windows and I made a .bat file with this the following command: sed s/.*/,"&",""/ Timecode.txt > NewTimecode.csv It will put the comma in the correct place but it doesn't put the timecode in quotation marks. Sorry for my ignorance. Also is it possible to delete the first line of the text file that shows %Frame Rate

Comment: Hi Ed, I didn't downvoter you. Your answer was a great help to me.

Comment: I have no idea about Windows .bat files, sorry, but in your comment it looks like you removed the single quotes from around the sed command. I hear quoting in Windows is a nightmare so maybe that's the issue. In Windows I use cygwin so I have a sane UNIX-like environment to code in. Yes, it is possible to delete any line but you'd need to  edit your question to show the new requirements, sample input and expected output.

Comment: Didn't down-vote, but I imagine they wanted more explanation.

Comment: can't imagine what kind of explanation THAT would require :-).